# Polymer Designer tool compatibility on the latest version of polymer?

Tags: polymer-designer-tool

Hi I am a newbie on learning polymer structure and managing api : is the polymer designer tool compatible with the latest version of polymer?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Polymer Designer currently uses the pre-1.0 syntax, which is not forward compatible. It [seems](https://github.com/Polymer/designer/issues/206) the project source was updated to a newer Polymer version, but the app deployment hasn't been touched:

> **justinfagnani** commented on Nov 20, 2015:
>
> This is true, the live site is very old now, but I've been resisting taking it down so that people still have access to their old projects. Maybe it's not that important though, as they still have them in gists.

Comment: Thanks for the info  @tony19 and jusitnfagnani.